# Activate features by code when site created -Onet.xml

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, feature-activation, onet

I created a new sub site from custom site template. I deployed my custom web template to this site collection. I create a new site and select my custom web template.

But I dont understand, why I need to do feature activation manually? Is it possible to activate features by code when site created?
Find my onet.xml code

```
<WebFeatures>
        <Feature ID="6e86842d-89db-4c4f-bd04-37f41dc28754"/>
        <Feature ID="891e49d5-a8ea-40c5-9930-ea3079fb7370"/>
</WebFeatures>
```

Comment: The features mentioned in `<WebFeatures>` should be automatically activated

Comment: It's not happen in newly created subsite(Using my custom site template). Any reason?

Comment: Are these features installed? Can you see them on site features page?

Comment: Yes, Features are there under site features. But not activated by default.

Comment: Few things, I would do to make sure everything is correct. The Scope of the features should be `Web`. Check that Id is correct. Finally, put a break point  in feature activation code and check if it is hit.